# Como comparar apenas a data com objetos do tipo Date?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data

Quero criar um grupo de funções que compara datas em TypeScript. Até o momento tenho as seguintes:

```
function amanhaOuDepois(date: Date): boolean{
    if(date > (new Date()))
        return true;
    return false;
}

function ontemOuAntes(date: Date): boolean{
    if(date < (new Date()))
        return true;
    return false;
}

function hoje(date: Date): boolean{
    if(date == (new Date()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Todas as funções estão funcionando de acordo com o esperado, menos a função `amanhaOuDepois`, que sempre retorna `false`. Como eu posso comparar apenas a data de um objeto de tipo `Date`, ignorando a hora, minutos e segundos?

Comment: só um adendo: `(date < (new Date()))` isso já retorna `true` ou `false` ... então só dá um `return date < new Date();`

Comment: Foi pra deixar o código um pouquinho mais legível hehehe, mas sim, você está com a razão

Comment: Tem duas funções com o mesmo nome: `amanhaOuDepois` ... observe isso ... acho que erro de digitação.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic corrigido, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você zerar a parte do tempo então sobra só a data para comparar. Pode fazer isto com [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours). Desta forma será comparado o *timestamp* só considerando a parte da data mesmo.

```js
let date = new Date(2019, 11, 3);
console.log(date);
console.log(new Date());
console.log(date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Então em TS ficaria algo assim:

```
function amanhaOuDepois(date: Date): boolean {
     return date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) > new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
function ontemOuAntes(date: Date): boolean {
     return date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) < new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
function hoje(date: Date): boolean {
     return date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/JustDateCompare.ts).

Isto não considera fuso horário.

Considere usar a biblioteca [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) para facilitar e ser mais confiável. Ela foi preparada para lidar com dados de tempo de forma mais adequada do que a maioria dos programadores fariam. [Funciona com TypeScript](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/3280).

Answer (score 2):

Compare pelo método [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) que [retorna o valor numérico correspondente ao horário da data especificada de acordo com o horário universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

***Exemplo:***

---

***Classe:***

```js
class DateTimeCompare {
  getDate(): Date {
    return new Date(new Date().toDateString());
  }
  getTime(): number {
    return this.getDate().getTime();
  }
  lessThan(date: Date): boolean {
    return date.getTime() < this.getTime();
  }
  moreThan(date: Date): boolean {
    return date.getTime() > this.getTime();
  }
  equal(date: Date): boolean {
    return date.getTime() === this.getTime();
  }
}

var dateEqualTrue = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
var dateEqualFalse = new Date();

var dateTimeCompare = new DateTimeCompare();
console.log(dateTimeCompare.equal(dateEqualTrue));  
console.log(dateTimeCompare.equal(dateEqualFalse));
```

<sup>***Referencia:***</sup>

- [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
- [Como comparar Datas e Horários em JavaScript - Passo a passo](https://metring.com.br/comparar-datas-e-horarios-em-javascript)
- [Javascript Date - set just the date, ignoring time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847806/javascript-date-set-just-the-date-ignoring-time)
- [TypeScript in 5 minutes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)